# Sequelize.js - bulkCreate - Issues between my API and DB

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to charge some data from a local API in my database with `bulkCreate` when the server turns on but I'm having this issue.

My model:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {

  sequelize.define('Country', {
    id : {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(3), //cca3
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey : true,
      validate:{
       len: {
        args: [3, 3],
        msg: ' 3 caract.',
      },
      
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    flag: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate :{
        isIn: [[".png"]],
        isUrl: true,
      }
    },
    continent: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('South America', 'North America', 'Oceania', 'Asia', 'Antarctica', 'Europe', 'Africa'),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    capital: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subregion: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    area:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    },
    population: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
    
  });
};
```

The code to load data in my database:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const api = ('http://localhost:5000/countries');
const {Country} = require("../models/Country")


module.exports = async() => {
    try {
        const {data} = await axios(api);

        const countries = data.map((ct) =>({
            
            id: ct.cca3,
            name: ct.name.common,
            flag: ct.flags.svg,
            continent : ct.continents[0],
            capital: ct.capital ? ct.capital[0] : "No Capital",
            subregion: ct.subregion ? ct.subregion : "No Data",
            area : ct.area,
            population: ct.population


        }
        ));       
        console.log(countries);
          await Country.bulkCreate(countries);

    } catch (error) {
            return null;
    } 
}
```

Check the line 24, that log shows this in console.

[image: console]

So at this point the code works but in my database from SQL Shell the data doesn't appear.

[image: sql shell]

I was expecting the data that shows in the console log already loaded in my db so i could use it to make some fun things.

PS: This is how I'm turning on the sv and trying to load the database

```
const server = require("./src/server");
const { conn } = require('./src/db.js');
const loadDb = require("./src/models/loadDb.js");
const PORT = 3001;



conn.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  loadDb ();
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: swap `console.log` and `bulkCreate` lines. Also you don't wait for the result in `listen` - is it intentional?